Ethernet devices on router cant ping or reach wireless devices
My homeserver pc is connected to router via ethernet and my wifi devices on the network cant reach it and they cant reach it. Wireless devices can contact each other and all devices can ping router and internet. router has no port forwarding

Do you have AP isolation turned on on your router?

Router doesn't have option. I found the problem ethernet and Wifi not bridged
